# Saving the Iptables rules to the iptables file

Tags: iptables, java, sudo

I am trying to save the iptables current rules to iptables file through my java application. Since i do not have the permission to write to the file without logging in to the root, am using this command.

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

When i type the above command without logging in to the root in terminal it works(save the rules to the file), how ever when i add the same command to my java program it doesn't work.

Below is the way i have implemented it in my program

..inside method

```
{
String command="sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables";
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
}
```

What seems to be the problem here ? Is there any other way of saving the iptables rules to the iptables file without logging in to the root?

Thank you

Comment: What is it logging when it fails?  How does it fail?

Comment: It doesn't show any error. It executes successfully, but it doesn't get saved.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts from `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: What is account running java program? I think this isn't permission sudo command.

Comment: @JennyD sorry didn't get what u said.

Comment: You are using sudo. Sudo is configured with the file `/etc/sudoers`. This is likely to be relevant.

Comment: You could also have a look at your sudo logs.

Comment: I suspect it is not, in fact, executing successfully, as `tee` exits with status `1` if it can't write the named file (for me).  Why do you think it is successful?  **Show** us your evidence; don't just **tell** us.

Comment: I think sudo don't have the password of the user and need it. So nothing should work. We definitively need the content of the `/etc/sudoers` file

Comment: "java exec pipeline": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088917/java-exec-does-not-return-expected-result-of-pipes-connected-commands http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 wow thanks alot. It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

When sudo invoked, it asks for the password of the user who started it - to ensure the person at the terminal is really the same "joe" who's listed in `/etc/sudoers`.

You must consider this behavior in your program.